# My laravel .env file is downloadable via ip access! How to solve this on litespeed server?

Tags: security, laravel, litespeed

hello I am creating a new laravel project with Openlitespeed server and I saw a glaring security issue.
I've added the following rule to the .htaccess of the site root and it works fine by stopping when someone tries to download the .env file by [www.mywebsite.com/.env](http://www.mywebsite.com/.env)
But to my surprise, it is possible to download the .env file easily by accessing the server IP, eg: 127.0.0.1/.env

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
# Disable Directory listing
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    </IfModule>

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php/(.+)\sHTTP [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NE,L,R]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    #RewriteRule !^(public/|index\.php) [NC,F]

    # block files which needs to be hidden // in here specify .example extension of the file
    <Files ~ "\.(env|json|config.js|md|gitignore|gitattributes|lock)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    satisfy all
    </Files>

    # in here specify full file name sperator '|'
    <Files ~ "(artisan)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    </Files>

    <Files *.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    </Files>

    <Files index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    </Files>
</IfModule>
```

the root structure of the laravel project is this https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSuaJ.jpg

how do I solve this? I have access to edit httpd_config.conf

Answer (score 0):

https://openlitespeed.org/kb/access-control/#articleTOC_4 gives examples how to block access to files.

Create a static context with URI being `/.env` and Location being `$DOC_ROOT/.env` and set it to `No` in Accessible.

However, your document root should be the `public` folder as per the Laravel documentation, if it's done as they suggest, you shouldn't even have to worry about accessing the `.env` file, since it will be one level above the path served by the webserver.

Comment: thanks for the tip, it made me think! And I went to investigate, I installed laravel incorrectly on the server. Now it's ok! As you said, I don't need .htaccess rules to block access to .env because the framework files are 1 level above the root directory